# gap between two divs when one has background-image

Tags: html, css

When I set `background-image` to one of the div and set the `background-size` as `contain`, there will be gap between two divs.

[image]

the code is below:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .header {
            height: 50px;
            background: url('https://xxx.png') no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        .footer {
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How to remove the gap?

Comment: Probably your image doesn't have the exact aspect ratio of the div. when you make the background-size : contain, it forces the image to fit in the div. make it "cover" and it will probably work.

Comment: @masoud Yes, this is the reason, thanks.